# knowing you have the right processor before installing python

Tags: python, installation, compatibility, startup, processor

Hi there im a newbie and just started to learn how to code using python recently. Im having problems installing it though. the prompt keeps bringing up an error that says 'this installation package is not supported by your processor type. contact your vendor" what does this mean and how can i resolve it? I'm using an Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU 2.20GHz 2 gig Ram

Comment: *windows 8pro OS

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to install the 64-bit version of Python on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: How are you trying to install Python? Where did you get the installation package?

Comment: trying to install from the their website.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2GB of RAM, you're probably using a 32-bit OS. You want 32-bit Python. Make sure you also select the correct OS when choosing a Python exe to download.

If you're using 32-bit Windows, I believe its the x86 from here: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/python-3.6.1.exe